# Error after compilation in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, theme

I am getting an error after compilation. I am using Magento 1.9.0.1.

My website was running too slow so I have complied but after compilation my website (frontend as well as backend) has down and showing the same error. Please help me to rectify the same.

**Error**: `Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/ecomventures/public_html/demo/includes/src/../lib/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='/home/ecomventures/public_html/demo/includes/src:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/ecomventures/public_html/demo/includes/src/Fontis_Australia_Model_Observer.php on line 23`

Comment: Compilation is no longer considered a Magento "best practice". I would argue that you should not use it and find other, more modern, methods of achieving the speed increase you're looking for.

Comment: Compiler was a kludge introduced around 1.4.1.1 and Magento was optimized to the point that it started to become mostly useless in 1.6.2.0 per A/B testing. The problems it introduces when 3rd party modules start being introduced to the mix often means it needs to be tossed in the corner where it belongs as a side note of history.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the index.php in your magento store
   Comments the below lines.

> /** 
>   * Compilation includes configuration file 
>   */

```
/**
$compilerConfig = ‘includes/config.php’; 
if (file_exists($compilerConfig)) { 
include $compilerConfig; 
} 
*/
```

Clean the cache dir and verify that its now working.

2. Another options, if you are able to open backend then go and disable complier
3. Disable via terminal
   $ php -f shell/compiler.php -- disable
   php -f shell/compiler.php -- clear
   php -f shell/compiler.php -- state